# Floating point arithmetic, optimizing mantissa multiplication

Tags: c++, floating-point, multiplication, mantissa

I implemented an arbitrary precision floating point class using Boosts `cpp_int` for the mantissa and it works fine (I am not using their `cpp_bin_floats` because I need to be able to dynamically change precision).

However, I think it might be possible to optimize multiplication. The way I am doing this now is:

1. Add the exponents.
2. Multiply the mantissas. We get a mantissa (about) twice the size.
3. Truncate / shift right the result mantissa, so it has the desired length and adjust the exponent accordingly

But that means, we calculated half the digits unnecessarily. Of course we can't just truncate the two multiplicands by half. That would give wrong results. Is there an amount I can truncate the multiplicands that gives no loss of precision?

One other thought is: When multiplying two 64 bit integers, I would need a 128 bit integer to hold the result. But I can also split the two multiplicands into high and low parts, calculate them crosswise and distribute the results into two 64 bit integers like this:

```
low = low_a * low_b;
mid1 = low_a * high_b;
mid2 = high_a * low_b;
high = high_a * high_b;

highResult = high + (mid1 >> 32) + (mid2 >> 32);
lowResult = low + (mid1 << 32) + (mid2 << 32);
```

Hopefully I didn't make a mistake here. But we can see: If we only keep `highResult` anyway, we don't need to calculate `low_a * low_b` (that might give us a "carry", but I think, that is not necessary for precision). So only 3 of the 4 multiplications are necessary. This holds for any number of bits my integers has. Also: Since I only use the high parts of the mid results, I could technically use a recursive approach.

Shouldn't that open up the possibility to accelerate multiplication? If so: How could I as efficiently as possible split two `cpp_int`? I could bitshift right by half the msb to get the high part. But I can't think of a quick operation to get the low part (first shifting right, then left again and then subtract from the original value would probably be slow for very long `cpp_int`, wouldn't it?).

Comment: I think for a precise result you (usually) need to do the full multiplication, especially when you want to round to the nearest result (and from an "arbitrary precision" library, I would expect precision).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat But if you have a `cpp_int` with arbitrary length, how do you get another one to `&` against to extract the lower bits?

Comment: Regarding, splitting a `cpp_int`, I don't know the details of that implementation, but multi-precision integers are usually stored as an array of "limbs", usually an array of the largest integer type supported by the architecture (`uint64_t` on 64bit CPUs). If you have access to that array, you can split that in two parts somehow.

Comment: I just did a naive calculation. Not sure if it is correct, but it would imply that the splitting approach would give exactly no advantage. `cpp_int` use the Karatsuba-Method which has complexity O(n^log2(3)). The split-approach would half "n", but we would have to do 3 times more multiplications. But `n^log2(3) == (n/2)log2(3) * 3` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Re ”Is there an amount I can truncate the multiplicands that gives no loss of precision?”: No. Consider any arbitrary result q and the next lower (or higher) representable value q'. Let r = (q+q')/2. r is the rounding point—any result just below r gets rounded to q, any result just higher gets rounded to q', when a round-to-nearest method is in use. Let x and y be the representable numbers bounding r. x and y differ by 1 ULP, but the required results of x•x and y•y differ. So you cannot lose accuracy at that level…

Comment: … It may be that the low bit of y is 0, so “truncating” y by 1 bit will yield y, and then the multiplication will still deliver the correct result. But that is mere happenstance; for other choices of q, the corresponding y will have a low bit of 1. That is, we can be sure there are cases, many cases, where losing the low bit will alter the result.

Comment: That said, when the truncation (or rounding) of the low bits is data driven, instead of an invariant amount, it can be possible to terminate the multiplication early. Once the multiplication has been determined to be definitely above or below the critical rounding point of the result, the result can be determined without calculation of further bits.

Comment: Same library provides `gmp_float` and `mpfr_float` with fixed and arbitrary digit count. You should just comply with the open license of the underlying implementation. **GMP**  uses **LGPL**, not boost license.

Comment: I gave up on getting GMP to work with windows...